# jQuery animate not working / no errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this simple jQ script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        $('#slide').animate({left: "100px"});
    })
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="slide" style="border:2px solid red; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; position:relative; left: -100px;">

</div>
<button id"click">click</button>
```

The div doesn't slide and I can't figure out what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a problem in your `button` line in HTML. Currently it is:

```
<button id"click">click</button>
```

But it should be:

```
<button id="click">click</button>
```

There should be an `=` sign in between `id` and its value. Other than that, everything else look fine to me. Have you made sure that your jQuery is included?

Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99y5uj4k/)** demo.